# Imagemagick update not installing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, vagrant

I am running `sudo apt-get update` on Vagrant but it is not working:

```
GPG error: http://us.ubuntu.mirror.atratoip.net raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall the missing keys like [this guy explains in this post](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.co.at/2011/08/fixing-gpg-keys-in-ubuntu.html)

examples from the site: 
How you can download the keys:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
```

after you have sucsessfully downloaded the missing keys you have to update again.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Plan B:

It seems like you are in a hurry!
If everything fails and you have to update that tool asap then just remove it from:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and get a new repository from here:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu
```

after adding the new repository do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again.

IF THIS FAILS AS WELL :

Try this and enter the following commands into your console:

```
apt-get clean            # Remove cached packages
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old       # Backup mirror info
mkdir -p lists/partial   # Recreate directory structure
apt-get clean
apt-get update           # Fetch mirror info
```

Comment: I am not able to understanding this ,i am totally new on vagrant . May you descibe in detail...please

Comment: sure, I've edited my answer check out the first 2 lines.